# No namespace support after upgrading Babel in React Native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, babeljs

I created a project using 'react-native init --typescript', upgraded react-native to 0.59.5, babel using npx babel-upgrade, installed and configured metro-react-native-babel-preset. However, now the log says that namespaces aren't supported. Is there something more that I'm meant to do?

I've tried cleaning the npm cache, deleting the node_modules directory and redoing npm install. I've even tried rebuilding the project.

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Ovik",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start --skipflow --reset-cache",
    "develop:android": "react-native run-android --no-packager",
    "develop:ios": "react-native run-ios --no-packager",
    "check": "tsc --noEmit || true"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "es6-symbol": "^3.1.1",
    "firebase": "^5.9.4",
    "futura": "^0.2.0",
    "geofire": "^5.0.1",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "^0.59.5",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^0.13.1",
    "react-native-slider": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-typography": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash.isequal": "^4.5.5",
    "@types/react": "^16.8.13",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.57.45",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.4.2",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.1",
    "patch-package": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.12",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.8.6",
    "tslint": "^5.16.0",
    "tslint-language-service": "^0.9.9",
    "typescript": "^3.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js"
    }
  }
}
```

I expected the project to bundle as it has before, however it gives the following error

```
error: bundling failed: SyntaxError: D:\Project\ovik\src\state\loading\index.ts: Namespaces are not supported.
  48 | /** Types */
  49 |
> 50 | export namespace Loading {
     |        ^
  51 |   export interface State {
  52 |   }
  53 |
    at File.buildCodeFrameError (D:\Project\ovik\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\file\file.js:261:12)
    at NodePath.buildCodeFrameError (D:\Project\ovik\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\index.js:157:21)
    at PluginPass.TSModuleDeclaration (D:\Project\ovik\node_modules\@babel\plugin-transform-typescript\lib\index.js:244:22)
    at newFn (D:\Project\ovik\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\visitors.js:193:21)
    at NodePath._call (D:\Project\ovik\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:53:20)
    at NodePath.call (D:\Project\ovik\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:40:17)
    at NodePath.visit (D:\Project\ovik\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\context.js:88:12)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (D:\Project\ovik\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\context.js:118:16)
```

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge to React Native is limited, but I do know quite a long about transpilers/bundlers.

Your upgrade clearly includes babel's new typescript preset or `transform-typescript` plugin. Like it said, `namespace` is not supported in babel. Reason being babel transpiles on a per-file basis, unlike typescript which takes project as a whole.

That caveat is gonna stay, not likely to get a fix in near future. So you either drop `namespace` usage, or switch back to previous config and continue to use `tsc` as a compiler.